# Creating Multiple Web App Forms under a single Project

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm very new to Google Scripts-- I'm trying to have a weekly submission and voting system for my research group.

I can't find any good documentation on `doGet(e)` so this may be a really stupid question. How can I make more than 1 web app form per project? I want to send 1 form for people to fill out with their paper submission -- which will populate a spreadsheet-- and another form later in the week for people to vote on those submissions.

Much thanks,
Ed

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one Ui instance in one project but it is very easy to have multiple panels in an UI (in a form as well) being visible under certain conditions... I'm currently working on a form that has 2 parts, one is visible during the first part of the week, the other during the second part... the panels are both in the same main panel and it appears exactly as if 2 versions where available depending on the date ;-)

My use case is for people ordering fruits and vegetables to a farmer but I guess the real purpose is not relevant ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Regards: doGet docs see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp and GUI Builder

This might help: doGet(params) {  ... } 
 i.e. pass parameters from the URL

You can use 2 scripts, (and open the spreadsheet by ID)